# Is `&T as *const T as *mut T` sound for `static mut` items?

Tags: rust, undefined-behavior

Imagine you're trying to write a safe wrapper around some mutable static:

```
#![feature(strict_provenance)]
#![deny(fuzzy_provenance_casts)]
#![deny(lossy_provenance_casts)]

struct Wrapper<T>(*mut T);
struct Guard<T>(*mut T);

impl<T> Wrapper<T> {
    fn guard(&self) -> Guard<T> {
        Guard(self.0)
    }
}

// imagine there's synchronization going on that makes this all safe
unsafe impl<T: Send + Sync> Sync for Wrapper<T> {}
impl<T> std::ops::Deref for Guard<T> {
    type Target = T;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        unsafe { &*self.0 }
    }
}
impl<T> std::ops::DerefMut for Guard<T> {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Target {
        unsafe { &mut *self.0 }
    }
}

static mut GLOBAL_SINGLETON: isize = 0; // Imagine this couldn't be trivially replaced by an atomic type
static WRAPPER: Wrapper<isize> = Wrapper(unsafe { &GLOBAL_SINGLETON as *const _ as *mut _ });
//                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                                             Is this sound in this sepcific instance?

// Actually dereference the raw pointer to provoke UB
fn main() {
    assert_eq!(0, *WRAPPER.guard());
    *WRAPPER.guard() += 1;
    assert_eq!(1, *WRAPPER.guard());
}
```

Now, usually it's unsound to cast `&T as *const T as *mut T` and write to the resulting raw pointer, but neither strict provenance nor Miri complain about the above code. Is this a false negative due to limitations of stacked borrows and/or Miri? Or do `static mut` items somehow get tagged as `SharedRW` globally and get a free pass here? A <kbd>Ctrl-F</kbd> for "static" in the [Stacked Borrows paper](https://plv.mpi-sws.org/rustbelt/stacked-borrows/paper.pdf) didn't reveal anything germane.

I had also considered something like this, which I would prefer because it forces `T` to outlive `Wrapper`.

```
struct Wrapper<'a, T>(&'a std::cell::UnsafeCell<T>);
impl<'a, T> Wrapper<'a, T> {
    const fn new(t: &'a T) -> Self {
        Self(unsafe { std::mem::transmute(t) }
    }
}
// ...

static mut GLOBAL_SINGLETON: isize = 0;
static WRAPPER: Wrapper<'_, isize> = Wrapper::new(&GLOBAL_SINGLETON);
// ...
```

but this is obviously unsound (which Miri will tell you) because it requires `&GLOBAL_SINGLETON` to be alive while `&UnsafeCell { GLOBAL_SINGLETON }` is alive.

Comment: Just a note that the Stacked Borrows model may be replaced -- emphasis on _may_ -- by the [Tree Borrows model](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/tree-borrows-explained/18587) instead which has slightly different rules.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Note that Stacked Borrows is not (yet?) the official memory model of Rust, and the decided memory model may be neither Stacked Borrows nor Tree Borrows.

Comment: It may also be interesting to look at [`feature(const_mut_refs)`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/57349) with which one can do `&mut GLOBAL_SINGLETON as *mut _` directly. This may hint at how a `static mut` is treated internally.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman That is a good point. The current memory model is more or less completely unspecified, right? Barring maybe the semantics of shared and mutable references?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Thanks for the pointer, I wasn't aware of that feature. I had looked at tree borrows when it showed up in the last issue of TWIR but considering that stacked borrows isn't even Rust's official memory model, I didn't really look into it further. I just chose to comply with stacked borrows because that's what Miri implements (I believe).

Comment: I would wager this should be classified as undefined behavior especially since current (sparse) documentation is very adamant that `&` to `&mut` is not allowed and doesn't qualify that any further with the storage class and since `&mut GLOBAL_SINGLETON` would be possible in this case in the future (Matthieu's comment). I'd see this as a false-negative from miri which says itself it does not catch all cases of undefined behavior.

Comment: @isaactfa: Miri actually implements both. Stacked Borrows is the default, and you can activate Tree Borrows by passing `-Zmiri-tree-borrows` (which is passed by environment variable...). Neither is official mostly because they are _working tools_ used to explore the domain and the impact of choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both existing answers state that this is UB, so I'm adding one of my own to reflect Ralf Jung's more nuanced input. If anybody would know, I reckon it's him:

> This is because we don't have an aliasing model at compile time, so nothing is remembering that this pointer originates from a shared reference. We also haven't made a decision on whether aliasing rules even apply at the boundary between compiletime and runtime. They are not super useful here I think since everything is global... But that is a UCG question. <sup>1</sup>

and

> It is deep in undecided/unspecified territory. So please don't do it. :) <sup>2</sup>

So this isn't definitely UB but it also isn't definitely not UB and should be avoided pending a decision.

Ralf also created [a new issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/unsafe-code-guidelines/issues/424) in the UCG repo to address this, so see that for future developments.

<sup>1</sup>: https://github.com/rust-lang/miri/issues/2937#issuecomment-1600365067

<sup>2</sup>: https://github.com/rust-lang/miri/issues/2937#issuecomment-1602458297

Answer (score 2):

1. It is immediate undefined behaviour because you cannot make `&mut T` from `&T` any way except when T is [`UnsafeCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.UnsafeCell.html).
   You must write something like this at least:

```rust
Wrapper(unsafe { &mut GLOBAL_SINGLETON as *mut _ })
```

MIRI doesn't catch this particular example but if you run simpler program, you can see that: https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b881d107244c95bd37d8fb3221a2b267

```rust
fn main(){
    let mut val = 5;
    let ptr = &val as *const i32;
    unsafe{
        *(ptr as *mut _) = 7;
    }
}
```

MIRI output:

```
error: Undefined Behavior: attempting a write access using <2665> at alloc1410[0x0], but that tag only grants SharedReadOnly permission for this location
 --> src/main.rs:6:9
  |
6 |         *(ptr as *mut _) = 7;
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |         |
  |         attempting a write access using <2665> at alloc1410[0x0], but that tag only grants SharedReadOnly permission for this location
  |         this error occurs as part of an access at alloc1410[0x0..0x4]
```

See also nomicon [entry](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/transmutes.html) about transmuting shared references to mutable references.

2. APIs of `Wrapper` and `Guard`, while not causing undefined behaviour by themselves, are still **unsound**. It means that you can trigger UB from safe Rust by using them.

For example, this would be UB:

```rust
fn foo(){
  let mut guard1 = WRAPPER.guard();
  *guard1 = 7;
  let mut guard2 = WRAPPER.guard();
  *guard2 = 5;
  // This access is UB
  assert_eq!(*guard1, 5);
}
```

It is very easy to get if you call any method of T because it is hard to track reentrancy. And it is even worse if you add multithreading to the mix.

I recommend to just don't use mutable statics because it is very inconvenient to access them soundly anyway.

I can imagine only this sound API for mutable statics:

```rust
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicUsize, Ordering};

pub fn access_mutable_static(
    // This `for <'a>` ensures that caller cannot store reference
    // to static anywhere.
    access_fn: impl for<'a> FnOnce(&'a mut i32),
) {
    static CURRENT_ACCESS_COUNT: AtomicUsize = AtomicUsize::new(0);
    static mut VALUE: i32 = 0;

    if CURRENT_ACCESS_COUNT.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Acquire) != 0 {
        // Relaxed here is OK because we haven't accessed `VALUE` yet.
        CURRENT_ACCESS_COUNT.fetch_sub(1, Ordering::Relaxed);
        panic!("Duplicate access to mutable static!");
    }

    // Use RAII because `access_fn` can panic.
    struct ReleaseAccessCount;
    impl Drop for ReleaseAccessCount {
        fn drop(&mut self) {
            CURRENT_ACCESS_COUNT.fetch_sub(1, Ordering::Release);
        }
    }

    let _guard = ReleaseAccessCount;
    unsafe {
        // SAFETY: function is safe because if static is being already accessed,
        // function would panic.
        access_fn(&mut VALUE);
    }
}

// Access like this:
let mut value_of_static: i32 = 0;
access_mutable_static(|s|value_of_static = *s);
let new_value = calc_value(value_of_static);
access_mutable_static(|s|*s = new_value);
```

Comment: I _believe_ you are right, but do you have a proof? After all, Miri does not report this. Not that it reports all Undefined Behaviors, but I feel like this _should_ have been reported if UB.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman See entry about transmuting references: https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/transmutes.html Coercing reference to pointer and dereferencing pointer is essentially same as transmute, only difference is that casting is more friendly to LLVM optimizer.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman If you use simpler program, MIRI would flag such cast: https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b881d107244c95bd37d8fb3221a2b267

Comment: That's not using `static mut`, that's a completely different matter.

Comment: It is same for correctness, only difference is complexity for compiler to analyze that since global memory cannot be really tracked. This is one of the reasons why acccess to `static mut` is unsafe: borrow checker cannot realistically track and verify that everything is OK.

Comment: We're not talking about borrow checker, but about Miri, which is a dynamic analyzer and should be able to do that pretty easily.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! These comments and answers made me realize that my question isn't really about aliasing (the rules of which I think I have a decent grip on) but on how static evaluation works in Rust; i.e. do those casts maybe get optimized away before borrow/provenance checking even applies.